# GWT project structure with UiBinder

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

If I have the following class `com.mywebapp.client.ui.MyWidget`:

```
public class MyWidget extends Composite {
    interface MyWidgetUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, MyWidget>{}
    private static MyWidgetUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(MyWidgetUiBinder.class);

    ...
}
```

And it's corresponding UiBinder:

```
<!-- MyWidgetUiBinder.ui.xml -->
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder' xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'>
    <!-- ... -->
</ui:UiBinder>
```

Then:

1. Where (what package or folder) does `MyWidgetUiBinder.ui.xml` go? Does GWT allow you to make this configurable or does it require that you place it somewhere specifically?
2. How granular should UiBinder snippets be? For every Widget? For every display region? 1 per "page"/screen?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UiBinder looks for a file named after the enclosing class of the interface (if any, otherwise the interface name), in the same package as that class.

In your case, it'll look for a `com/mywebapp/client/ui/MyWidget.ui.xml`.

This is the default, and can be overridden using `@UiTemplate`. See https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder#Apply_different_xml

As for the *granularity*, UiBinder templates should be kept an implementation detail of a widget.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas Broyer (+1) - do you mind if I ask why you like the "*1-UiBinder-per-Widget*" strategy, instead of using a UiBinder to layout the main parts of a page, and then delegating the details of a display region to panels and widgets? I'm just curious as to what benefits both strategies offer. Thanks again!

Comment: I bet you "main parts of a page" will end up being a widget containing other widgets (that you'd push into `SimplePanel`s and the like); you could then use UiBinder to define the internals/layout of that container widget, but that's an implementation details: from the outside, it's just a widget that contains other widgets. Case made.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Where (what package or folder) does MyWidgetUiBinder.ui.xml go? Does GWT allow you to make this configurable or does it require that you place it somewhere specifically?

GWT requires the ui.xml file to be in the same folder (the source folder) as the .java file. If you use the GWT plugin for eclipse, it will warn you if the file isn't there. You can also use the `@UiTemplate` annotation on your interface (`MyWidgetUiBinder`) to specify different location if you really need to.

> 1. How granular should UiBinder snippets be? For every Widget? For every display region? 1 per "page"/screen?

That really depends. I like to start with a single UiBinder per page, and then break the re-useable parts out of that.

Comment: Thanks @logan (+1) - (1) what if I have `src/java/com.mywebapp.client.ui.MyWidget` and then `src/xml/gwt/ui-binders/MyWidgetUiBinder.ui.xml`? Can I make that work with `@UiTemplate`? And (2) Your answer about the granularity conflicts with another answer to this question. I'm *sure* its subjective and application-specific, but can you speak to how your strategy works for you better than a "*1-UiBinder-per-Widget*" strategy? Thanks again!

Comment: Thomas works for Google. He knows what he's talking about. You definitely need one UiBinder per widget, I was just arguing for one widget per page as a starting point.